# php+mysql insert with on duplicate key with multiple matches

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i'm trying to create a script that will do the following:

1. When user clicks button, it will add them to the database and give them points for for the prod they clicked the button with.
2. If they already exist within the database, with that prod, instead of inserting a new entry into the database, it should instead, update their points by adding to the existing value.

This is what i have so far, but it doesn't seem to work (at some point in time, it would insert, but not update, now it appears to do neither)

```
//build the query - the command/request to give to the database
$query = "INSERT INTO client (client.usrKey, client.name, client.prod, client.stage, client.points) VALUES
('" . $avatar_key . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $prod . "', '" . $stage . "', '" . $points ."')      
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `points` = `points` +" . $points . " WHERE `slKey` = '" . $avatar_key . "' AND `prod` = '" . $prod . "'";
```

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

It's also entirely possible that i have taken the wrong approach to solving this issue, but after searching for days, every inference to my situation comes with strong advice to use the on duplicate key function.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the key on the table? usrKey, slKey? prod? Your update uses a totally different value as a key than what you are inserting.

Comment: Provide more information please. We help you but we can't read your mind

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you re-think about "how this stuff should works"

1. First when the user click on the button you have to check if that user exists
2. If exists then update the point else you insert it.

You have to build 3 Query (**I'm assuming that avatar_key is the Primary Key**):

```
$fetch_client = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE userKey = '".$avatar_key."'";
// Check if exists with PHP and Mysql you know what to do :)
if($clientExists){
$update_client = "UPDATE client SET ... WHERE userKey = '".$avatar_key."'";
}else{
$insert_client = "INSERT INTO client (...) VALUES (...)";
}
```

Comment: What the OP is trying to do is fine, it just looks like he doesn't have his key values straight.

Comment: @BNL He/she does not provide enough information to assume that :/

Answer (score 0):

You're slightly overthinking the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` - syntax.

Take a look at [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), there you'll find this basic example:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

In your case that would approximately look like:

```
INSERT INTO client (`usrKey`, `name`, `prod`, `stage`, `points`) VALUES
    ('whatever', 'values', 'needed', 'in', 'there')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `points` = `points` + your_points;
```

(slightly simplified to give you a feeling on how the end product should look like, you should know your steps from here and wrap it into php code).

You also can also break this down in more than one task, depending on the needs of your application.